# How can I make a program run in the background from a console application in c#

Tags: c#, console, batch-file

Hi there I am currently working on a Console Application that run's a .bat file and when the program starts it pops up as the main box on my window and as this is running several times a min, this can get a little annoying is there any way when I run this command...

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"newmessage1.bat");
```

is there a way of making the .bat cmd window running in a kinda hidden state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could play around a little with the [`CreateNoWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) and [`UseShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) properties:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "newmessage1.bat",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) property.

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"newmessage1.bat";
myProcess.Start();
```